# Medical test OFII in France

Tags: france, student-visa

I was wondering if anyone could give a small summary of what happens at the medical test at the OFII in France. I have read a few comments on the internet and one of them mentioned that they give the option of producing a chest X-ray taken in the native country (in my case, India). Since I'd be taking a copy of the chest X-ray to apply for an UK Visa later on, I was curious if I could just produce one such to the French authorities as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity where about are you coming from? Are you sure a medical examination is even required? It isn't always as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Iguananaut : India, if it makes any difference. I'm guessing the medical examination is required, at least as per the current data that's accessible on the internet and the OFII document.

Comment: OP, I'd like to add a word of advice; get there early. You have an appointment, but so do 50+ other people. People will generally be in a queue from 5am onward (for a morning appointment).You don't need to get there that early, but try for half an hour early. The queue will lose all semblance of order, there's a lot of shoving. This varies by your prefecture, of course. Otherwise, everything that the answer below says is correct! And if you're a lone female, in my experience, don't start chatting with anyone. That part may just be my bad experience talking though.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique: That's valuable advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It consists of chest x-ray and then a stop in a doctor's office.

The chest x-ray is to detect TB.

The doctor's visit (beyond looking at the x-ray) is for prevention purposes only: they ask you questions about life habits (smoking, drinking, etc.), about possible undiagnosed eyesight problems, etc. It is possible that you get a very quick eyesight check as well, but I've only had that happen to me on one such visit (because I've done two...)

As for your question, it is possible that they accept your chest x-ray, but in all cases that will not free you from the visit unfortunately :) As it has a wider purpose. All in all it takes a few hours.

Comment: Guess I'll have to get xrayed twice in all probability :)